# Change styling for input element in child component from parent component using state or props

Tags: reactjs

I am looking at how I can update the border-box for an input element in my child component (**UpdateInputBox**) by passing a new class as a prop from the parent component (**TextInput**). If I inspect the input element, I can see the new class getting added to the input element but the styling doesn't update.

I have a feeling this is because my child component may not be rendering on props change.

Code below:

**JSX File**

```
  import React from 'react';
    import styles from './styles.scss';

    export default class TextInput extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                selectedStateForText: 'textInputNonFocussed'
            }
            this.changeInputState = this.changeInputState.bind(this);
    }

    changeInputState(e) {
        this.setState({
            selectedStateForText: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <h1>Individual input Test Component</h1>
                <UpdateInputBox updateClass={this.state.selectedStateForText}/>
                <form className='textInputStyleSelector' onChange={this.changeInputState.bind(this)}>
                    <input type='radio' name='class' value='textInputNonFocussedValid' checked={this.state.selectedStateForText === 'textInputNonFocussedValid'} />Non-Focussed Valid
                    <input type='radio' name='class' value='textInputFocussedValid' checked={this.state.selectedStateForText === 'textInputFocussedValid'} />Focussed Valid
                    <input type='radio' name='class' value='textInputNonFocussedInvalid' checked={this.state.selectedStateForText === 'textInputNonFocussedInvalid'} />Non-Focussed Invalid
                </form>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

class UpdateInputBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            updateClass: props.updateClass
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input id='inputStyleComponents' className={this.state.updateClass} placeholder='Label text *' type='text' />
        );
    }
}
```

**Style SCSS file**

```
$titanium: #686868;
$font-input-placeholder: Regular;
$font-size-small: 12px;
$emerald: #3dc238;
$ruby: #a3403e;

.textInputContainer {
  background-color: white;
}


.inputStyleComponents {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}

// placeholder default css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: $titanium;
  font-family: $font-input-placeholder;
  font-size: $font-size-small;
}
::-moz-placeholder { 
  color: $titanium;
  font-family: $font-input-placeholder;
  font-size: $font-size-small;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { 
  color: $titanium;
  font-family: $font-input-placeholder;
  font-size: $font-size-small;
}


// Text Field Non Focussed class (styles can be applied to the input element but defining a class for testing)
input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid $titanium;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: none;
}

input[type=text]:focus, .textInputFocussed {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px lavender;
}

.textInputNonFocussedValid {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px $emerald;
}

.textInputFocussedValid {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px springgreen;
}

.textInputNonFocussedInvalid {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px $ruby;
}

.textInputFocussedInvalid {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px crimson;
}

input[type=text]:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type=radio] {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your parent component state updates, your child state does not gets updated like you believe. The `UpdateInputBox` constructor will run only once and so your state for `UpdateInputBox` will be set only once. You have to update your `UpdateInputBox` state, based on the `props` you receive in the `componentWillReceiveProps`. You have to do something like below. Hope this helps.

```
class UpdateInputBox extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        updateClass: props.updateClass
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 if(this.props.updateClass !== nextProps.updateClass) {
   this.setState({updateClass: nextProps.updateClass});
 }
}

render() {
    return (
        <input id='inputStyleComponents' className={this.state.updateClass} placeholder='Label text *' type='text' />
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks this helped me with fixing it. I have added a comment below with more information about what additional changes I had to make

Answer (score 0):

Check the classname in the `scss` file. I don't see any rule defined for the the class `textInputNonFocussed`. Try defining a rule for this class with the styles you wanted to apply.

Eg:

```
input.textInputNonFocussed {
    color: gray;
}
```

This should solve the problem as you have mentioned that the class is added.

Comment: That is intentional. Basically, I want to add a class based on the radio inputs and then update the styling of the input element by passing that class as a prop.

If you select a radio element and inspect the input element you will see that the class is added but the styling doesn't change. Styling for the classes used in the radio element are present in the css file

Answer (score 0):

@Panther:

The React Lifecycle hook helped me with getting the updated values. I had to make some additional changes to the code though as I am importing the .scss file and storing it as styles

```
import styles from './styles.scss';
```

because of that I had to use my classNames as:

```
<input className={styles.textInputFocussedValid} placeholder='Label text *' type='text' />
```

As my new class value is stored in the state using:

```
<input className={this.state.updateClass} placeholder='Label text *' type='text' />
```

didn't work (as it is not linked to styles like `styles.textInputFocussedValid`).

I eventually used classnames by JedWatson to create the conditions as below:

```
const updatedClass = classnames(
 { [`${styles.textInputNonFocussedValid}`]: this.props.updateClass === 'textInputNonFocussedValid' },
 { [`${styles.textInputFocussedValid}`]: this.props.updateClass === 'textInputFocussedValid' },
 { [`${styles.textInputNonFocussedInvalid}`]: this.props.updateClass === 'textInputNonFocussedInvalid' },
 { [`${styles.textInputNonFocussedValid}`]: this.props.updateClass === 'textInputNonFocussedValid' },
 { [`${styles.textInputFocussedInvalid}`]: this.props.updateClass === 'textInputFocussedInvalid' },
        );
        return (
            <input id='inputStyleComponents' className={updatedClass} placeholder='Label text *'type='text' />
        );
```